# passing const char in argv main argument

Tags: c++, string, char

I have the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    char *INPUTFILE_DATABASE = "";
    strcpy(INPUTFILE_DATABASE, argv[1]);    
    if(INPUTFILE_DATABASE[0]=='\0')
    {
        cout << "No input file given" << endl;
        INPUTFILE_DATABASE="File_name.csv";
    }
    cout << "Input file: " << INPUTFILE_DATABASE << endl;

    return 0;
```

when I compile, I receive:

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
  char *INPUTFILE_DATABASE = "";
```

When I make `char *INPUTFILE_DATABASE` as `const char *INPUTFILE_DATABASE` I cannot change it anymore, of course not. 
What am I doing wrong? Or is my motiviation not doable in general in this way?

Finally, I only want to allow to change the input file name but when no file name is given, a standard file name shall be used.

Comment: use std:string instead of char*

Comment: String constants are constant whether you label them as such or not, and as you can see you should always use `const`. On top of this you're trying to `strcpy` to a location that has only a single null byte allocated, so not only are you attempting to write to read-only memory, but you have an overflow too.

Comment: Why all the down votes? This question is well asked. Probably a duplicate if you search, though I don't see anyone linking to an original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you shouldn't do this. Instead of this:

```
char *INPUTFILE_DATABASE = "";
```

You should do something such as

```
char INPUTFILE_DATABASE[32]; // or another size that is sufficent
```

What happens when you do `char *INPUTFILE_DATABASE = "";` is that your `char*` will point to a position that is made to hold just `""` (so probably that's just going to be a byte of value `0` somewhere in the program's binary). You can't write to there.

Also, since this is C++, I would recommend:

```
std::string INPUTFILE_DATABASE = argv[1];
```

And instead of `if(INPUTFILE_DATABASE[0]=='\0')` you could do `if (!INPUTFILE_DATABASE.size())`

Comment: but when I do this I get: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char [27]’ to ‘char [200]’
   INPUTFILE_DATABASE="file_name.csv";

Comment: You still have to use `strcpy` if you're going to use a c style string.

Comment: Well, OP needs to use string, and that's it. All other answers are not helpful and incomplete (**const** char* is not char*).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Except using `string` would be way overkill here and isn't necessary at all.

Comment: "" ain't 0 byte, it still contains '\0'

Comment: With "0 byte" I meant a byte with value `0`, perhaps I should word that better.

Answer (score 3):

You never could change it. It's just that, thanks to old C rules, it *looked like* you could. The change in the rules (deprecation in C++98; actually this is illegal since C++11 and won't compile) is to better remind you of that.

To change the string, copy it to something you own, ideally using a `std::string`, particularly since your grasp of C-strings doesn't appear to be terribly strong (you have a zero-length string you're trying to copy a potentially-non-zero-length string on top of!).

In fact, I wouldn't copy anything, but re-arrange your logic to *conditionally* initialise `INPUTFILE_DATABASE` with something that is still an original constant string, like this:

```
// Use argv[1] if given and non-empty, otherwise a default path
const char* INPUTFILE_DATABASE = (
   argc > 1 && argv[1][0] != '\0'
   ? argv[1]
   : "File_name.csv"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::string` which manages the internal `char` buffer for you. As an example,

```
#include <string>

std::string INPUTFILE_DATABASE;

if (argc == 1)
   INPUTFILE_DATABASE = "File_name.csv";
else
   INPUTFILE_DATABASE = argv[1];
```

Comment: Pointer is enough here, no need to possibly allocate memory and copy the string.

Comment: That's true, though I wouldn't expect this to be a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be any more complicated then:

```
char const* INPUTFILE_DATABASE = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "File_name.csv";
```

Comment: `argc > 1 && argv[1][0] != '\0'` (or use `strlen` for clarity) but yes

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't modify this string either way, making it a `char const *` prevents you from making a bug.

First of all: don't do this, just use `std::string` instead. If helps you a lot in reducing the amounts of stupid bugs that appear with C-style strings.

To come back to your issue:

```
auto i = std::make_unique<char[]>(512); // or more? (Could be calculated at runtime)
std::strcpy(i.get(), argv[1]);
if (i[0]=='\0')
    {
        cout << "No input file given" << endl;
        std::strcpy(i.get(), "filename.csv");
    }
cout << "Input file: " << i.get() << std::endl;
```

Off course, working directly with char* requires you to know the amount of characters. As mentioned before, `std:: string` makes things easier:

```
auto i = std::string(argc[1]);
if (i.empty())
    {
        cout << "No input file given" << endl;
        i = "filename.csv";
    }
cout << "Input file: " << i << std::endl;
```

For this specific case, `std::string_view` should also work.

Note that `Lightness Races in Orbit` posted yet another variant that doesn't require you to potentially allocate memory for this specific case using just `char const *`